# Thread scheduling priority and niceness

Tags: multithreading, real-time, scheduling

Under GNU/Linux, niceness represents thread scheduling priority. Lowest niceness corresponds to highest priority.

Considering only scheduler based on priorities (no time slicing), is anyone aware of a wide-spread OS implementation where the behaviour would be different, i.e. highest niceness corresponds to highest priority?

Comment: The idea of nice is to be nice to other processes, so higher values mean the process is nicer to others (letting them use the CPU more). So if "highest niceness corresponds to highest priority", it would possibly not be called niceness ;-)

Comment: I use the word "niceness" to denote the numerical value used by the OS to manage scheduling priority, and then not mess it with the intent of the priority. But I agree, it wouldn't be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems with "priority" is that its semantics are overloaded in practice. Formally, it is a mechanism with the minimal semantics that it induces an uninterpreted  partial ordering. So scheduling eligibility can be denoted by larger to smaller priority integers interpreted as more to less eligible, or in the opposite order. But different systems and users employ the priority mechanism with several different additional richer semantics. In some cases, priority is interpreted as urgency. In some other cases it is interpreted as relative importance. It is even occasionally used for establishing precedence. Your question implies associating priority with the semantics of GNU/Linux "niceness." You asked if anyone knows of a wide-spread OS that has the reverse semantics. As the other replies noted, that would make priority have the semantics of "un-niceness." Strictly speaking, that is not the same as making the niceness-based priorities work "backwards." So your question is ill-formed. I am unaware of any OS that has niceness semantics and assigns priorities in un-nice order. You might have been thinking of whether there are wide-spread OS's in which scheduling eligibility is inversely related to priority integers--the answer to that is "yes." But note that too is not a well-formed question: by definition (admittedly not widely understood) scheduling eligibility is the same as uninterpreted priority per se, unless additional semantics are added to "priority." For example, if priority is specified as an 8-bit integer, the semantics of scheduling eligibility can be that larger priorities correspond to greater eligibility, or that smaller ones correspond to greater eligibility--each option has been chosen by various OS's.

Comment: What's magical with your answer is that you precisely determined what my true question actually was. And, indeed, you answers it pretty well ;)